# Cannot use extra_option with path django

Tags: python, django

I don't understand why I cannot use the `path()` method as documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions in my apps `urls.py`.

Here is the code I have:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views as AliasViews
from permissions import views as PermissionsViews

    urlpatterns = [
    ...
        path(r'^user/(?P<alias_id>\d{1,})/members/?$', 
             AliasViews.UserAliasMember.as_view(), 
             name='useralias_member', {'alias_type':'UserAlias'}),
    ...    
    ]
```

I get this error: `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the `path` function. As the error says, Python syntax does not allow keyword arguments - eg `name='useralias_member'` - before non-keyword arguments. Your extra dictionary should be *before* that name argument.

Note however that you're also confusing `path` with `url`. The new `path` function doesn't use regexes, it uses the special `<arg:type>` format. If you want to use regexes, switch back to `url`.

Comment: Thanks so my path call should look like this:         "path('/user/<int:alias_id>/members/', AliasViews.UserAliasMember.as_view(), {'alias_type':'UserAlias'})" right?

Comment: hmmm I made the suggested code change now I get an error message: "ImportError: cannot import name path"

Comment: Are you actually using Django 2.0?

Comment: Thanks Daniel ... looks like I am running django 1.11.